# Run .net app in Vista/Windows 7 as admin

Tags: winforms, security, windows-7, windows-vista

I have created .NET winforms application and setup project for it.
What I need is that after installation, my application always runs with administrator privileges.

Could someone tell me how I can configure my application to do that? Can I do it just by modifying source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a manifest file to your project and set the "requireAdministrator" settings. e.g.

1. Right click your project, add file
2. Select app manifest
3. Open the file and make your `requestedExecutionLevel` match:

   `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

If it's already installed, you can locate the exe and select properties. In the `Compatibility` tab, check the box at the bottom "Run this program as an administrator".